# Resolving hostname in linux (pwnpi)

Tags: linux, networking, dns, arp

i am having problems with wget on linux. After little research i found out that i cant get reply from dns server.

But its really strange because other windows machine (in same network switch) can access the dns.

Wireshark gives me info about that linux machine is sending arp requests for dns into network but cant get reply from it.

On windows machine it seems like that it doesnt send arp request for dns servers, but it just send to dns ip address with mac of default gateway which could be resolved by arp on both machines.

What could be wrong?

linux ip is 10.20.5.1 mask: 255.255.252.0
default gw: 10.20.4.1
dns addresses on: 10.230.6.12 10.230.6.13

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming question but I'm curious.

You're not on the same network as the dns servers so if you want send traffic to the dns you have to go through the gateway hence I would expect an arp request for the gateway and not for the dns

If your machine is really doing arp for the dns address then that makes me believe that your netmask is not what you say it is (maybe not configured hence /8 -- the std for a class A network)

Can you output:

- ip a sh
- ip route get 10.230.6.12

Rgds

MArcel

Comment: strange, the thing is working now, i dont know what was wrong. It makes dns requests even if server is not in the same network.

Comment: sure it will make dns requests. I was talking about an arp request for the dns ip address

Comment: yeah, it looked like that gateway doesnt want to forward request.